# Restrict file type in the window?

Tags: javascript, html, json, file-upload, upload

```
<input name="uploadJsonFile" type="file" id="uploadJsonFileID" accept=".json">
```

- I am using HTML file type element to upload a file.
- When i click on "choose files" button, a window is getting opened.
- Initially in that window, its showing only ".json" files but there is possible to select "Allfiles".
- Is there any way to block it?
- I want only the ".json" option in the opened window. No need of "Allfiles" option.
- Anything can be done using javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Not really, in the end it's completely up to the browser. HTML cannot *force* anything, it can only describe and recommend. You will need to check the actually uploaded file on the server anyway.